# Node.js connect-modrewrite combined with express

Tags: node.js, mod-rewrite, express

I would like to ask you how to use url rewriting with mod_rewrite on node.js. Creators of `connect-modrewrite` prepared examples [here](https://www.npmjs.org/package/connect-modrewrite) but unfortunately in case of `express` this example is not valid, in present version method `configure` is deprecated.

Standard syntax is:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});
http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening for clients on *:3000');
});
```

I've tryed to combine standard syntax with `connect-modrewrite`, something like:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var modRewrite = require('connect-modrewrite');
app.get(modRewrite([
    '^/test$ /index.html',
    '^/test/\\d*$ /index.html [L]',
    '^/test/\\d*/\\d*$ /flag.html [L]'
]), function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});
http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening for clients on *:3000');
});
```

This throws following error:

```
(...)node_modules/express/node_modules/path-to-regexp/index.js:34
.concat(strict ? '' : '/?')
```

I'm blocked here. If anyone has an idea, I will be greatfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some support from the author of connect-modrewrite :) here's the solution:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
app.use(modRewrite([
    '^/test$ /index.html',
    '^/test/\\d*$ /index.html [L]',
    '^/test/\\d*/\\d*$ /flag.html [L]'
]));
app.get('/index.html', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});
http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening for clients on *:3000');
});
```

Works perfectly! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I used based on Marek's answer. The idea is that Express non-static routes will not apply here. For all static routes, you want to make sure some of them will keep unchanged, and some of them will be rewritten to another destination, ex. here I made sure everything else goes to index.html if it's not from styles, scripts, images, fonts, and files folder.

But if you have a express route already setup, '/city', it'll still kept same.

```
var modRewrite = require('connect-modrewrite');
app.use(modRewrite([
                                        // express route has been taken care of, and won't enter here. 
    '^/styles/(.*)$ - [L]',             // keep
    '^/scripts/(.*)$ - [L]',            // keep
    '^/images/(.*)$ - [L]',             // keep
    '^/fonts/(.*)$ - [L]',              // keep
    '^/files/(.*)$ - [L]',              // keep
    '^/.*$ /index.html'                 // for whatever else, use index.html
    //'^((?!api).)*$ /index.html'         // for non-api routes, use index.html
]));
app.use(express.static(global.appRoot + config.www));
```